# Include modules translation file outside module in Yii

Tags: yii2, yii-modules

I have Yii application with following structure
application/

```
    /framework
    /protect
        /modules
           /report
              /translation
               lang.php
        /views
        /controller
        /model
```

I have working language translation inside module, But When I try to access language file lang.php from the view of the protected directory outside modules with following code

Yii::t('ReportModule.lang','Report Title');

It shows error.

include(VreportModule.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

How to make modules language file accessible outside the module ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Advanced template I did this in main.php, You probably need to do this inside your web.php

```
 'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'general*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@backend/messages/general',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
            ],
          ],
       ],
```

And now I can access Yii::t('general','message'); Everywhere
The folder structure is:

```
\BasePath
    \language_code example( nl or nl_NL )
       \language file this time it's general.php
```

More information: [Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-i18n.html)